# Javascript calling function from inside same function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, while-loop, callback

I have a function that does several DDBB calls, so it is asynchronous.

I need to call the function and check a data value (winner) in the JSON object it returns. If it is true i need to call the function again until winner == false.

I can't use while because it is not asynchronous, how can i do this?

```
  someFunction(function(result) {
     // if result.winner == true repeat 
  })
```

Comment: Put the call to the function inside the success where the results are actually returned.

Comment: Could you include the whole code snippet ? I'm specifically referring to the function which gets the code from the database.

Comment: @fornal you mean calling the function from inside the same function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the same callback function again until condition is `true`:

```
someFunction(function repeat(result) {
    if (result.winner) {
        someFunction(repeat);
    }
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
someFunction(function repeat(result) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + result.winner;
    if (result.winner) {
        someFunction(repeat);
    }
});

var results = [true, true, true, false];
function someFunction(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback({winner: results.shift()});
    }, (Math.random() + 1) * 1000 | 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at async.js? It has several control flow async functions. You probably want to look into whilst, doWhilst, until, doUntil:

https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst

```
whilst(test, fn, callback)
```

Repeatedly call fn, while test returns true. Calls callback when stopped, or an error occurs.